# populate multiple select boxes with single json string

Tags: javascript, json

I have string of data coming to the page via ajax. in the following format

```
[{"servername":"svrA"},{"servername":"svrB"},{"servername":"svrC"},{"location":"locA"},{"location":"locB"},{"location":"locC"}]
```

I'd like to populate two select boxes with the data.

I've tried different variations of the following pseudo code:

```
for each item in the json string
if obj == servername
   add to selectbox Server
if obj == location
   add to selectbox Location
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Trevor3.0, Could you please post the last version of the code you've tried please.

Comment: First, post your _actual_ code - pseudocode doesn't help at all, and second, you need to say what's not working as opposed to "any ideas would be appreciated"

Comment: where should I post it? just <edit> my current question?

Comment: @Trevor3.0 Indeed, edit requested information into the existing question

Answer (score 1):

```
var stuff = [{"servername":"svrA"},{"servername":"svrB"},{"servername":"svrC"},{"location":"locA"},{"location":"locB"},{"location":"locC"}];

var elems = {
    "servername": jQuery('#select-server'),
    "location": jQuery('#select-location')
};

stuff.forEach(function(item){
    for(var selectName in elems){
        if(typeof item[selectName] != 'undefined'){
            var val = item[selectName];
            elems[selectName].append(jQuery('<option/>').val(val).html(val));
        }
    }
});
```

Not that `forEach` is not available on older browsers. The code above is just a sample for you to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this and depending on how your code might evolve in the future, some solutions might be slightly better than others or more flexible, but since I do not have such knowledge, here's an example on how you could do it in vanilla JS.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rXc23/)**

```
var data = [
        {"servername":"svrA"},
        {"servername":"svrB"},
        {"servername":"svrC"},
        {"location":"locA"},
        {"location":"locB"},
        {"location":"locC"}
    ],
    selects = {
        servername: document.getElementById('servername'),
        location: document.getElementById('location')
    }, 
    i = 0,
    len = data.length,
    item, prop, val;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    prop = 'servername' in (item = data[i])? 'servername' : 'location';
    val = item[prop];
    selects[prop].add(new Option(val, val), null);
}
```

If you plan having the same kind of data structure for multiple select boxes, instead of hardcoding the `selects` object that references the `select` elements, you could also have pulled the select `id` dynamically using `for in` and also resolve the `select` reference using a generic approach.